# PHP include files from different folders

Tags: php, include, directory, root

I have 2 files index.php and header.php and both of them are in different folders.

```
root/en/index.php

root/includes/header.php
```

I tried to setup the root folder with a config.php file (placed in the root directory):

```
DEFINE("ROOT_PATH", dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );
```

In index.php, if I try to include any of the pages (header.php or confing.php) the path still starts from the index.php subfolder (en) and not from the root. In index.php I use:

```
include( ROOT_PATH . "/config.php");

include( ROOT_PATH . "/includes/header.php");
```

The result is:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH'
>
> Warning: include(ROOT_PATH/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in root/eng/index.php.

---

So I tried without the confing.php (as i though including the file in a subfolder will change the root folder) but it still doesn't work..

I'm on localhost, using XAMP.

Comment: You have to read your error

Comment: is your file root/en/index.php? I think it should be root/eng/index.php

Comment: @executable is spot on there. There is a lot of information in the error message that suggests that your constant is not properly defined, and that the path is built up incorrectly because of that. An alternative solution is to use relative paths that go up, for instance `include '../includes/header.php';` should allow you to include that file from index.php. But if you get new error messages when you try that, you should again read and interpret them.

Comment: index.php is placed in root/en folder. Sorry for "eng" i modified the path to look simplet here and accidentally typed eng instead of en.
The problem is that i can't manage to go from root/en/ to root

Comment: I guess both of you are reffering to the ROOT constant that is not properly defined.
I already went on forums and tutorials to understand how that works and it seems fine, i don't get why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

did you know  , you can use include like this :

```
include '../../config.php';
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work and it returns the same error: Warning: include(../../includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\en\index.php on line 20

Comment: where is config.php file location, and where you call the config.php directory ?

Comment: root/confing.php and i call it in root/en/index.php - so i have to go one step up and i tried ../confing.php, ./config.php and your answer path and it doesn't work..

Comment: can you posted the index.php file here ?

Comment: So.. it works from /root/en/index.php with include '../config.php; I didn't know because i tested only with include '../includes/header.php'; and for some reason XAMP doesn't show this files in the folder, so the PHP code can't find it anyway... The problem is that i can't use '../path' for the entire site because it's not very secure to use static paths.. I don't know how to post the index file sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have config.php as

```
DEFINE("ROOT_PATH", dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );
```

which has definition of ROOT_PATH itself. So whenever you need ROOT_PATH you need to have config.php included first.

if the config.php file is in root/config.php and you need to call the file from root/en/index.php then you need to have,

```
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/config.php');
include( ROOT_PATH . "/includes/header.php");
```

then the code will work.

Edit:

```
echo dirname(__DIR__).'/config.php'
exit;
```

Run this code on the file you are calling.. you know what the file you are trying to include and check with the directory structure that you are getting same directory information in code

Comment: i tried and it doesn't work. From what i understood, when config.php is included in index.php, the code will run and the root directory will be where index.php is (so root/en/..)

Comment: I am assuming you define root/ as your ROOT_PATH and config file is in root/config.php and you are calling the file from root/en/index.php. If it is not let me know the location of config.php file

Comment: You are correct. the config file is in the root folder.

Comment: I think you may have two versions of xampp and installed in two different drives / directories and running the code with another version of xampp / apache running.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** This must be done in the same file. 
  *  (Or in a file whose import does not depend on the 'ROOT_PATH' constant.)
  **/
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );

include( ROOT_PATH . "/config.php");

include( ROOT_PATH . "/includes/header.php");
```